# Java FX editing null values in a table

Tags: java, javafx

I have a table view which contains a few objects. I've made a few fields editable and as long as the field originally has a value, the editing works great: double click to start editing, enter to commit the new value.

However if the original field is "null", the editing does not work: double click to start editing still works but if you hit enter, the "editstart" event is triggered again instead of the editcommit.

I've found a few references to this problem online (both on stack overflow and elsewhere) but few actual solutions apart from providing default values (which is not always possible or desirable)

Comment: Does it work if you set an empty string as default value?

Comment: This would be the default value solution, it works but does not apply to all data types nor is desirable for the database backend.